# Printing docs in original format from OneNote

Tags: printing, microsoft-onenote

In Microsoft OneNote 2007, if I print to OneNote using the OneNote print driver, or if I use "Insert -> Files as printouts", or if I scan a multiple-page document into OneNote, I get a bunch of images in my notebook, each image representing a page in the file I printed/imported into OneNote.

What I'm looking for is an easy way to subsequently print those "images" to a real printer, so they look exactly like they originally did.  That is, I don't want any extra margins, headers, etc. in the printout.

(I plan to upgrade to Office 2010 before too long, so information pertaining to OneNote 2010 is also welcome.)

Answer (score 2):

My solution, which seems a little clunky, is to right-click and save the image from OneNote to file.

I then print that image using the photo printing wizard at full page fax print size.

The result is pretty close to the original, and if you always use the same name (default = notes.jpg) they continue to overwrite so you don't have to clean it out.